# Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Hy, 
 I am stuck with the following error:

'Uncaught typeError: Cannot set property '5' of undefined'

the code being this:

```
    function blank2dArray( width,height) 
    { 
       var result=[[]];//matrix
      for(var i=0;i<width;i++) 
      {
          result[i]=new Array(height);
      } 
      return result; 
    }


 function generate()
    {
       var r=blank2dArray(width,height);  //generates a blank matrix
       for(var i=0;i<across.length;i++) 
       { 
         var word=across[i]; 
         for(var j=0;j<across[i].length;j++) 
         { 
           r[ax[i]+j][ay[i]]=word[j]; //at some point ay[i]=5
         } 
       }
    }

across-it is an array of words;
ax-array of numbers
ay-array of numbers
```

If I replace ax[i] and ay[i] with  any number, it looks like it works. But this is not the way it is supposed to act.
Thank you.

Comment: The problem is in your logic. at some point in time, `r[ax[i]+j][ay[i]]` returns undefined. Since we don't know what `r` `ax` or `ay` are, that's about as much as we can tell you. Can you show an example of how you would use this code so that we can re-create it and help debug it?

Comment: @KevinB: Specifically, at some point in time `r[ax[i]+j]` is `undefined`.

Comment: BTW, your `blank2dArray` function creates and then throws away an array and suggests you may want to look again at your understanding of how arrays in JavaScript work. Your initializer should just be `var result = [];` (note, not `[[]]`), since you then populate the outer array with the code that follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, guess I solved it. It happened because ax[i] it's a string, and ax[i]+j is therefore invalid. All i did was parseInt(ax[i])+j.That way the matrix is populated corespondantly.

Answer (score 0):

At some point, `r[ax[i]+j][ay[i]]` is undefined, probably because `ax[i] + j` is greater than its length, and you cannot assign a value to an **undefined** object.